# Managing single-spa application state and sharing it with others

Tags: state-management, micro-frontend, single-spa

I'm in a process of creating architecture for a single-spa application, and wanted to ask, is it a good idea to use redux for state management in each particular app, and then for the common state of the whole application use something like rxjs? Or maybe there's another way about this.

As of this moment all applications will be using only react.

Comment: As I don't have a definite answer, I'll just comment this:  I think that, if you adhere to ES modules all over, module sharing is a great sharing tool.  You can share stores among micro-frontends very easily.  Still, I haven't fully experimented with this, so I cannot blindly recommend it.  I'm working on gaining experience myself.